Date on y axis in ggplot?
I'm struggling to plot date (month and day) on the y-axis in ggplot in R. If I use serial date (column named D50) that excel converts my dates into, it plots fine, but the labels in the y-axis show up as the serial date and not in the mm dd format. If I use the dates (column named D502), the plot looks totally different than I want. Any help would be appreciated! Here's the data called flowdist;
example data
This looks fine, but I want the month and day on the y-axis, not the serial date:
ggplot(flowdist, aes(x = water.year, y = D50)) + 
  geom_line() +
  theme_classic()

serial date on y-axis
This gives a super weird result I don't understand where ggplot groups days and then months:
ggplot(flowdist, aes(x = water.year, y = D502)) + 
  geom_line() +
  theme_classic()

calendar date on y-axis
There's a ton of info about dates on the x-axis, but not too much on date as a response on the y-axis. Thanks!
